# what is use of delegate that I am not able to distinguish

Tags: jquery

On Jquery 'delegation', I am not able to understand this delegating events, Any help on this?

what if i use,

case 1

```
$( "table td" ).on( "click", function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "chosen" );
});
```

case 2

```
$( "table" ).delegate( "td", "click", function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "chosen" );
});
```

Both will do the same job. If so, what is the main difference?[I am not able to understand]. Is anything related to 'Event Bubbling'? Please

Comment: first one - there is no event delegation - to use delegation `$( "table" ).on( "click", "td", function() {});`

Comment: @ArunPJohny, Actually, I am lacking in understanding 'delegation'. You are not making sense that i try to understand. Could you please read my question and answer?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8qukx12t/1/ - Look at this example - The elements added after the handler is added is not getting executed if delegation was not used

Comment: @ArunPJohny, I am not able to understand anything, As far as I understand, all 'td' are working when I click on the table. I could not see the difference and Importance on delegation.

Comment: @User123 Only the first element gets the first listener that sets the `chosen` class. All elements (created later) get the other two listeners that set `chosen2` and `chosen3`, because those listeners are set via delegation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Direct vs. Delegated - jQuery .on()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The practical difference is that `delegate` (and three-argument `on`) can cause listeners to apply to elements that don't exist yet.

`$( "table td" ).on( "click", ...)` attaches a listener to every element that matches the `table td` selector that exists *at the time the call is made*. If a `td` is added to the page after this call, it won't have a listener attached to it.

`$( "table" ).delegate( "td", "click", ...)` attaches a listener to every `table` that exists at the time the call is made, and that listener only fires when a `td` sub-element of that `table` element is clicked.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("tr").append("<td>I am added after page-load time and am not targeted by load-time scripts. The listener that fires an alert does not apply to me, because I didn't exist when the <code>$('table td').click</code> code ran. However, the delegated listener still aplies, so I will turn red when you click me.</td>");
})

$("table td").on("click", function() { alert("hi"); });

$("table").delegate("td", "click", function() { $(this).css("color", "red"); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:70%";>
  <tr>
    <td>I am targeted by non-delegated event listeners set at page-load time. Click this text to trun this text red and see an alert.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>Add another td</button>
```

Delegation works because when you click a child element (like a `td`) you've actually clicked all of its parents (like a `table` and the `body`) as well. (To compare to human person: you can't poke a person's arm without also poking that person as a whole.) When a click listener fires for a parent, the event has a [`target` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) that indicates what element was the original target of the event.

```js
document.getElementById("theDiv").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if(e.target != this) {
      e.target.style.color = "red";
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="theDiv">
  <span>I'm a span, inside of a div</span><br/>
  <span>I'm another span, inside of a div</span><br/>
  <span>I'm a third span, inside of a div</span>
</div>
```

Note in this example, we add only one listener on the `<div>`. When we click a `<span>`, the `click` event also applies to the parent `<div>`. We use `event.target` to allow the `<div>` listener to find out which of its children was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1 binds the `onclick` handler for all `<td>` nodes that are **already present in DOM** at the moment you bind that handler. If you decide to add another `<td>` dynamically to your table, your event handler won't be called for this new `<td>`.

Case 2, which in fact should look like this (since `As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method`):

```
$( "table" ).on( "click", "td", function() {
  ...
});
```

is there to overcome the issue described above. I.e. your event handler will be called even for the `<td>` nodes added dynamically **after** the moment you bind that handler.

More info: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/